# Disable VS Code javascript check

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, twig

I am passing a twig object to javascript via script tags in a .html.twig file, and VS Code complains that "Property assignment expected. js [17, 38]". Is it possible to turn this off completely for .html.twig-files or perhaps turn off checking altogether? I am using ESLint extension in any case.

```
    <script>
    ...
    window.PROPS = {{ props|json_encode|raw }};
    ...
    </script>
```

[image: Problems that are really not problems and that I wish to get rid of.]

(edit) Just to clarify, ESLint is not responsible for these problem-messages. I can turn off the ESLint extension (and reload the window); the messages remain.

Comment: If you want to turn it off altogether, you can disable the ESLint extension

Comment: Edited my question: ESLint is not the culprit.

Comment: Are you using prettier or something like that?

Comment: @leofalmeida No, and to be safe I just disabled all my VS Code extensions and reloaded the window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is another setting in VS Code for Javascript inside `script` tags:

in settings.json, set

```
"html.validate.scripts": false
```

Comment: Additional note: in case you have a .htmlhintrc file in your work directory, `"html.validate.scripts": false` in settings.json is ignored if property `"jshint": true` is present in .htmlhintrc

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off JavaScript validation off through the `javascript.validate.enable` setting in VS Code settings.

[image]

Comment: Edited my question: ESLint is not the culprit.

Comment: Unbelievably, the problem messages are still there. 
I just found another setting that was the issue. Thanks for your help, @Shahzad B

Comment: @Sheepwall what was the setting?

Comment: @Olli This was a long time ago, but it might be the accepted answer

Comment: @Sheepwall I see thanks! in my case it was a the svelte plugin.