# Selectively disable VS Code JS validation errors in HTML-embedded scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I'm using the `onclick` attribute in Django HTML templates to dynamically set arguments to JavaScript function calls, like this:

```
<button onclick="activateSomething( argumentOne, {{ some_django_var }} )">Click Me</button>
```

VS Code's [built-in embedded-scripts validation for HTML](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_validation) flags several syntax errors in such a construction, however, because it doesn't understand the Django template syntax. I could [disable that validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056875/disable-vs-code-javascript-check), but that would be overkill, I still need the validation in other areas of my templates.

So the question is, is it currently possible to disable only specific JS errors, perhaps on a line-by-line basis à la `# pylint: disable=some-error-type`?